# Aligning vertical dots in a chunk of equations

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

I understand that similar questions have been posed before, but somehow, I do not know how to fit the answers into the context of the problem that I am facing.

Specifically, I have the following block of equations:

```
\begin{align*}
a_{2k}&=a_{2k-1}+a_k \\&=a_{2(k-1)+1}+a_k\\&=a_{2(k-1)}+a_k
\\&= a_{2k-3}+a_{k-1}+a_k \\&=a_{2(k-2)+1}+a_{k-1}+a_k
\\&= a_{2(k-2)}+a_{k-1}+a_k \\&= a_{2k-5}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-1}+a_k
\\& \vdots
\\& = a_1+a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_k
\end{align*}
```

The problem is that the vertical dots appear on the extreme left, but I want them more centralised. Is there a way to fix this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Basically the solution to this class of problems is to define the 
    `\vdotswithin` command and then specify the amount of space needed, for example 200/300 mu or whatever.

Comment: You not need to define `\vdotswithin`. It is defined in the `mathtools` package as is stated in my answer.  Better than add this to your question is to extend your code fragment to MWE :-).

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: Related: [Vertical alignment of dots in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144913)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `\vdotswithin` defined in the `mathtools` package you can do on two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
a_{2k}
&=a_{2k-1}+a_k \\
&=a_{2(k-1)+1}+a_k\\
&=a_{2(k-1)}+a_k
\\&= a_{2k-3}+a_{k-1}+a_k \\
&=a_{2(k-2)+1}+a_{k-1}+a_k\\
&= a_{2(k-2)}+a_{k-1}+a_k \\
&= a_{2k-5}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-1}+a_k\\
& \vdotswithin{=}\\
& = a_1+a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_k
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a_{2k}
&=a_{2k-1}+a_k \\
&=a_{2(k-1)+1}+a_k\\
&=a_{2(k-1)}+a_k
\\&= a_{2k-3}+a_{k-1}+a_k \\
&=a_{2(k-2)+1}+a_{k-1}+a_k\\
&= a_{2(k-2)}+a_{k-1}+a_k \\
&= a_{2k-5}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-1}+a_k\\
& \vdotswithin{\mspace{200mu}}\\
& = a_1+a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_k
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for your help.